# Output of List varies while using loops on Varargs

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Outputs of the code is varies on iterating with Varargs.
Please let me know what is the reason for different outputs.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Integer[] a = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3};
        Integer[] b = new Integer[]{4, 5, 6};
        
        
        List<Object> list1=new ArrayList<>();
        addAllObj1(list1, a,b);
        System.out.println(list1); //[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@24d46ca6, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@4517d9a3]
        
        List<Object> list2=new ArrayList<>();
        addAllObj2(list2, a,b);
        System.out.println(list2); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
    
    private static void addAllObj1(List<Object> list, Object[]... arr) {
        for(Object o:arr) {
            Collections.addAll(list, o);
        }
    }
    
    private static void addAllObj2(List<Object> list, Object[]... arr) {
        Collections.addAll(list, arr[0]);
        Collections.addAll(list, arr[1]);
    }

}
```

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry for posting a wrong answer, but I think I found the solution now within the [Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/index.html). Here is how I understand it:

I think the following explains it:

```
private static void addAllObj2(List<Object> list, Object[]... arr) {
    Object o = arr[0];
    Collections.addAll(list, o);
    Collections.addAll(list, arr[1]);
}
```

returns:

```
[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@75a1cd57, 4, 5, 6]
```

The line with index 1 does work, because during runtime, the jvm evaluates the arity parameters [the the type of the input will not be rewritten](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2) The conversion to `Integer` apparently is possible. (I guess the type of `b` will not be changed)

In the line with index 0, the type will be evaluated and rewritten due to [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6), as it will be stored as the Object `o`. The Type of the Object `o` and `a` (Integer[]) is not the same, therefore erasure takes place and it will be converted to an Object, hence the reference name.

This process apparently only takes place with arity parameters, as without:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    addAllObj3(list3, trePConcat(a, b));
    System.out.println(list3);

    
}

private static void addAllObj3(List<Object> list, Object[] arr) {
    Collections.addAll(list, arr[0]);
    Collections.addAll(list, arr[1]);
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static Object[] trePConcat(Object[]... arr) {
    return arr;
}
```

returns

```
[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@75a1cd57, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@3d012ddd]
```

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of `final` at the end of your answer.

Comment: There's no type erasure happening here, there are no raw types involved. Assigning an expression of a subtype to a supertype variable is simply a widening reference conversion. That alone doesn't explain it. Also, the JVM doesn't _evaluate the arity_ at runtime. Method selection is done statically, at compile time. (Unless that's not what you meant.)